# grub-pc update-error on Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: grub, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After `sudo apt upgrade` following error constantly appears:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.11) ...
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rootfs'.
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rootfs'.
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rootfs'.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rootfs'.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Windows 10 build 14393

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this github comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143#issuecomment-209072634) and the one directly below it (for copy pasteable script) for some solution that worked for me.

For ease of anyone visiting, here's the comment's important text (though you should thumbs up the guy on the github comment if you're able):

(I had to do it after running `sudo -s` or prefixing each line with `sudo`)

```
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
EOF
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

Comment: this error occurs when i attempt:
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
followed the instructions but problem persists

Comment: Not working for me, any workaround? On Ubuntu 16.04 for Windows

Comment: @LorenzoPeña Haven't had this issue for a while now. Maybe check that github issue for any updates?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to wipe my WLS install and start from scratch. Thanks for the reply. Won't try to install docker in WLS again ;)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt -f remove grub-pc
```

From https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1965#issuecomment-340132015: